# Perl Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at.. WWW::Mechanize::Timed

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

**I have the following very simple piece of code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize::Timed;
my $ua = WWW::Mechanize::Timed->new();
my $url = 'www.stackoverflow.com';

$ua->get($url);    
print "Total time: " . $ua->client_total_time . "\n";
print "Elapsed time: " . $ua->client_elapsed_time . "\n";
```

**The error I am getting:**

When running the program I sometimes get the following error, it does not happen all the time, its seems to appear intermittently.

`Use of uninitialized value in addition (+) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/WWW/Mechanize/Timed.pm line 52.`

**Is there something obvious I am overlooking, as I cant understand why this error is occurring, let alone why it only happens sometimes?**

Your help is much appreciated, many thanks

Comment: You should finish the message: `at ...` what line and what file? Also consider using `Carp::Always` to get a more helpful message.

Comment: @mob - added the rest of the error to my question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that

```
my $url = 'www.stackoverflow.com';
```

is not an actual URL.  That's just a host name.  Are you saying that your program sometimes works without specifying the `http://` scheme?  You need

```
my $url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
```

Also, you want to check the return code from `->get()`, or add `autocheck => 1` to the constructor.  At some point in ::Mechanize's history that became the default, but I don't know what version you're on.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, thank you very much. In my program each of the urls were being parsed in from a large text file, it just so happened that a few of the urls were being put into the text file without the `http://` prefix, which is why the problem only seemed to be occurring occasionally when it came across these urls without the `http://`, thanks for your quick answer.